# Using Message or Interface-based approach to return List<T> from AsyncTask?

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, memory-consumption

I am aware that there are multiple approaches on how to return some data from `AsyncTask` to the calling `Activity`. I can use `Message` object from the `Handler` or I can use `Interface-based` approach with both `Activity` and my `AsyncTask` implementing the same interface (with method that passes the data).

And then again there are other approaches like with the `public` method in the calling `Activity` and passing that `Activity` to the `AsyncTask` and then filling `Activity's` field list with the result data. Or overriding `onPostExecute` from the calling `Activity`, and so on, and so on.

Now, **in terms of memory consumption and speed of execution**, which approach is the BEST to use?

**NOTE:** If we take the rating of SO experts, I saw that guys with 20k+ rating suggest either `Message` or `Interface-based` approaches. Some less experienced, but still with 10k+ credit, suggest other solutions like the 3rd one I mentioned. That is the root of my confusion because no one of them mentioned anything about how "heavy" their solution is.

Comment: the third option is like a interface, only without the interface. you'll depend on having this specific activity, meaning that a/ you won't be able to use it somewhere else, or to move the call to the async task to another activity/service/fragment and b/ you'll have a lesser separation between your ui and that controller. It implies the risk that you create more links between the two (such as using the activity passed to the asynctask as a context to create views or dialogs in the asynctask, which would start to smell bad.)

Comment: also, I strongly recommend you take a look at the implementation of async task. interesting reading. you'll see that asynctask uses handler and messages to communicate between the 2 threads (UI and background). That's the most common use of that mean of communication, passing data between 2 threads. when you are on the same thread (such as doing stuff on the ui in your activity and the execution of `onPostExecute`) you don't need your data to switch thread. messages are overkill in this case.

Comment: (I suppose you mean overriding `onPostExecute` in the calling Activity? otherwise that's just defining the asynctask in the activity (which works, until you need to use the asynctask somewhere else))

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks, so your suggestions is to use Interface-based method. To be frank, `Message` approached seems heavy to me as well, but could not dare to say anything myself. About overriding, You are right. I will fix the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing activity is not a good approach. Because that is a burden on memory.(All the fields are loaded in memory from previous activity). Also it makes the 2 activities tightly bound.

The first 2 are the correct approach depending upon the scenario.

1. Message based communication  consumes a lot of android OS resource. As for every message received the OS looks for all the handlers associated with it. It is used mostly when your activity has to communicate to various other activities also activities external to your application.
2. Interface based / Callback method is more preferential in your case . If your activity has to communicate to fewer activities and within your application. It would consume lesser memory and and computation overhead from android OS